# Xcode tests - not showing up in the left hand sidebar

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

Adding tests to a test unit in xcode doesn't show them up on the tests inspector (left hand side bar).

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have followed the instructions of tutorials to a T.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have the problem where no tests are showing up at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The test method names need to begin with the word 'test'.

i.e. `apiWillLoginWithKnownEmailAndPassword` should be `testApiWillLoginWithKnownEmailAndPassword`